# Expo EAS Submit always prompts for Apple Developer Account

Tags: ios, react-native, continuous-integration, expo, eas

I build and submit my Expo app via this command:

`eas build --profile preview --auto-submit --platform all`

Like mentioned in the [Eas submit docs](https://docs.expo.dev/submit/ios/#submitting-your-app-using-ci), I provided `appleId`, `appleTeamId` and `ascAppId` to my eas.json like this:

```json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 1.0.0",
    "promptToConfigurePushNotifications": false
  },
  "build": {
  ...
  },
  "submit": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
       ...
      },
      "ios": {
        "appleId": "[myAppleId]",
        "appleTeamId": "[myAppleTeamId]",
        "ascAppId": "[myAscAppId]"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, theoretically submit should be **completely autonomous**. **But** I am always requested by the CLI to
*"Log in to your Apple Developer account to continue"*. The credentials are prefilled, but I need to hit 'y' two times, which means the command **can not run in CI**.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already submitted at least one version to the app store?
If not, you'll have to manually submit one first.
Otherwise here you'll probably just need to have 2 env variables set for the `eas submit` command:

1. `EXPO_APPLE_PASSWORD`: the password of the Apple account `myAppleId`
2. `EXPO_APPLE_APP_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD`: a password for the specific app you are submitting ([See here on how to set this up](https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/apple-app-specific-password.md))

You'll also need the `--non-interactive` flag for `eas submit`

Main doc here https://docs.expo.dev/submit/ios/

Comment: Adding the `--non-interactive` flag works, even if I use `eas build` with `--auto-submit` rather than `eas submit`. Thank you!

Comment: Did you use CI to build and submit? I've got a hard time making this work as looks like submission do not support filed api_key and I do not want to save *.p8 in repo.